# Ranking with no duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rank a large dataset using python. I do not want duplicates and rather than using the 'first' method, I would instead like it to look at another column and rank it based on that value.

It should only look at the second column if the rank in the first column has duplicates.

```
Name   CountA CountB
Alpha  15     3
Beta   20     52
Delta  20     31
Gamma  45     43
```

I would like the ranking to end up

```
Name   CountA CountB Rank
Alpha  15     3      4
Beta   20     52     2
Delta  20     31     3
Gamma  45     43     1
```

Currently, I am using `df.rank(ascending=False, method='first')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use sort and pull out the index:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','D'],'CountA':[15,20,20,45],'CountB':[3,52,31,43]}) 
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['CountA','CountB'],ascending=False).index + 1 

  Name  CountA  CountB  rank
0    A      15       3     4
1    B      20      52     2
2    C      20      31     3
3    D      45      43     1
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, I `sort_values` on Count B and then did `rank(method=" first")` on Count A.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the counts of the values in CountA and then filter the DataFrame rows based on the count of CountA being greater than 1. Where the count is greater than 1, take CountB, otherwise CountA.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[15,3],[20,52],[20,31],[45,43]],columns=['CountA','CountB'])

colAcount = df['CountA'].value_counts()

#then take the indices where colACount > 1 and use them in a where

df['final'] = df['CountA'].where(~df['CountA'].isin(colAcount[colAcount>1].index),df['CountB'])

df = df.sort_values(by='final', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

# the rank is the index
   CountA  CountB  final
0      20      52     52
1      45      43     45
2      20      31     31
3      15       3     15
```

See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You seemed to answer a slightly different question. The issue is that the correct index order(based on your indexes) would be 1,0,2,3. I was not looking to replace the values but only have CountB used as a tie breaker.

Comment: Gotcha. Interesting question.